# Insert to parent and child tables

Tags: nhibernate

Hi 
I have parent and child table like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

                    ------- parent --------------
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="HibernateSample.StudMarks,HibernateSample" table="StudMarks" lazy="false">
    <id name="Sno" column="SNO" type="int">
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Student" column="ID" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="Marks" column="Marks" type="int" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Rank" column="Rank" type="int" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

               ------- child --------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="HibernateSample.Student,HibernateSample" table="Student" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" column="ID" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="Name" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Standard" column="Standard" type="string" not-null="true" />
    <bag name="StudMarks" cascade="all" lazy="false">
      <key column="ID" not-null="true"/>
      <one-to-many class="HibernateSample.StudMarks,HibernateSample" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and in .cs file i have like written code like below to insert into parent and child.

```
        StudMarks sm = new StudMarks(); 
        Student st = new Student();
        List<StudMarks> sms = new List<StudMarks>();
        st.Id = 9;
        st.Name = "stud 999";
        st.Standard = "99";
        sm.Sno = 9;
        sm.Marks = 99;
        sm.Rank = 9;            

        sm.Student = st;              ------ **Line 1**
        st.StudMarks = sms;           ------ **Line 2**

        session.Save(sm);            
        session.Flush();
```

If i commENT "Line 1" in above code only child is inserting. If i comment "Line 2" foreign key constraint error is throwing.

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, -- PRIMARY KEY
[Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Standard] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudMarks](
[SNO] [int] NOT NULL, -- PRIMARY KEY
[ID] [int] NOT NULL, -- FOREIGN KEY
[Marks] [int] NOT NULL,
[Rank] [int] NOT NULL,)
```

Please let me know how to insert in parent and child at a time in single save operation.

Comment: Any reason you're not adding 'sm' into 'sms' list before assigning to st.StudMarks?

Comment: i added sms.Add(sm); before "Line 1" and is working without changing hbm file. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have a cascade relation from Student->StudentMarks. So you should be saving st...

```
session.Save(st);
```

You should also specify inverse="true" on the bag so you don't get double updates of the foreign key and a cascade="all-delete-orphan" is probably appropriate here as you want all StudentMarks to be deleted when the Student is deleted.

Comment: i added sms.Add(sm); before "Line 1" and is working without changing hbm file. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify `inverse="true"` on the `Student` mapping of the StudMarks collection property, indicating that the `StudMark` mapping is the owner of the relationship.